# VBA InsertRow issue

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code to insert a new row keeping the same format: 
source code:https://www.developpez.net/forums/d869670/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/ajout-ligne-gardant-mise-forme/

```
Sub Ajout_Ligne()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
    .Insert
    .Copy
    .Offset(-1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The problem is that it keeps the same color for instance but not the borders (screen below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a copied row.

```
Sub Ajout_Ligne()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveCell.entirerow
        .Copy
        .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?.

```
Sub Macro()
    'Copy formatting from row 1, copy to last row
    '
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End Sub
```

I kow everyone will say "whoa he's using select, big no no", but something this small it shouldn't make a difference.